# dnsimple redirect HTTPS URL to another extension using single SSL cert

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl

I have a website with many extensions. The DNS is manage by DNSimple.
I bought a SSL Wildcard cert for my .co extension. I would like to be able to redirect https://example.fr to https://example.co through DNSimple without purchasing another SSL Wildcard for the other extensions.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible to do the redirects without SSL for the other sites. Try letsencrypt.org, if you don't need wildcard for other domains.